# ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, exception

I've seen this error everywhere, but none of the solutions have seemed to work.

**This is my code:**

`contpayment = driver.find_element_by_class_name('nsg-bg--nike-orange')`

`contpayment.click()`

Python/selenium finds this element perfectly, but when trying to click it throws an eception:

```
"ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible"
```

I've even tried adding a `time.sleep(10)` to ensure the page has completely loaded, but it still returns the same exception... Even finding by XPath and id gives the same.

**Here is the HTML Code:**

```
<button type="button" id="shippingSubmit" name="shipSubmit" class="visible-
xs-block  hidden-sm nsg-button--thin nsg-bg--nike-orange uppercase change-
section-button ng-binding" ng-click="sendForm('Payment')">Continue to Payment </button>
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Please share the html code.

Comment: html code has been added

Comment: what if you use find_elements_by_class_name instead of find_element_by_class_name? How many items are returned? That might happen that you have both visible and invisible items matching locator. And the invisible one goes prior to visible.

Answer (score 4):

1.Use following **XPath** Locators:

```
//button[contains(@id,'shippingSubmit') and (@name,'shipSubmit')];

OR

//button[contains(@id,'shippingSubmit') and starts-with(@class,'visible-xs-block')];

OR

//button[contains(.,'Continue to Payment')];
```

2. Add **Explicit Wait** before clicking to the particular button.

```
contpayment = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'Continue to Payment')]")))

contpayment.click()
```

Comment: updated code plz check.

Comment: if one not works, Try changing all other XPath.

Comment: Does it work's for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebDriverWait` and `visibility_of_element_located` to locate the element until the element is visible.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "shippingSubmit")))    
element.click()
```

**Alternative:**

In case, waiting for the element for visibility is not working, try `execute_script`.

```
driver.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).click();", element)
```

Comment: That seemed to work however, it looks like the button is like permanently invisible because I just got a timeout exception... weird

Comment: See the alternative way.

Comment: still getting timeout :/

Answer (score 0):

Use this below XPath this will work.

```
driver.findElementByXpath("//button[contains(text(),'Continue to Payment')]");
```

This xpath will locate the button directly.