# ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible Selenium in Python

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, chromedriver

I'm trying  to  click an options from a website dropdown menu  but I am not able to click.

I am using "xpath" locators for the element and I upgraded my chrome to the latest version for chromedriver.

I am using:

- chrome=68.0.3440.106
- chromedriver=2.41.578700
- platform=Linux 4.15.0-30

Code snippet that contains error line:

```
    def test_adsz(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("url")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@alt='Dersomani']").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"(//a[contains(text(),'Sınıf')])[2]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"(//a[contains(text(),'ÜYE GİRİŞİ')])[2]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_name("email").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("admin")
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("12345")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='alın'])[1]/following::button[1]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@alt='User Name']").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"(//a[contains(text(),'Yönetici')])[2]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_link_text(u"Üye Listesi").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Tanım İşlemleri'])[1]/following::span[1]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Profilim").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='logged_in']/a").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"(//a[contains(text(),'Çıkış Yap')])[2]").click()
```

My error line:

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"(//a[contains(text(),'Sınıf')])[2]").click()
```

My traceback info:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"(//a[contains(text(),'Sınıf')]) 
[2]").click()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 628, in 
_execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in 
check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible`
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/33880/elementnotvisibleexception-message-element-not-visible?rq=1 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927964/selenium-element-not-visible-exception may be related / help you

Comment: share some code that produces the issue.

Comment: I've added the code snippet and the error line. @AlexeyR.

Comment: but due to the error you have posted, your error line is `driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"(//a[contains(text(),'1. Sınıf')]) 
[2]").click()` however you mention line `driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"(//a[contains(text(),'Sınıf')])[2]").click()`. So eventually which line does produce the error?

Comment: I edited  traceback info area. Error line is  `driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"(//a[contains(text(),'Sınıf')])[2]").click()` @AlexeyR.

Comment: Could you please check if before clicking on any of options you are clicking on the drop-down element to list down all the options.
If no, then please make sure you click on the drop-down element so that all the options are visible and you might also check in-case
you need to scroll the page in order to interact with the intended element.

Comment: Actually , I tried  this solution, this  is working  for some of dropdown menus but  not working  for some  dropdowns, I don't understand what is the difference between dropdowns. Thank you @KshetraMohanPrusty

Comment: Check for proper synchronization and make sure that when you are interacting with a dropdown element, that is literally visible. You might need to scroll sometimes when the drop-down has lot more elements or the expansion moves below the visible range of the page.

Comment: How is the dropdown populated?

Comment: it is populating upside of the page and opening top-down. @gumol

Comment: Did you try using another API to find the drop-down? such as by CSS?

Comment: It is working with Css selector and I added  time.sleep() between some code lines, thanks a lot @gumol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find the reason why the element is not visible at that point. Is the element marked as display:none or hidden by a hide element class? Or maybe is it not visible because there's some other element on top of it or out of visible page borders?

Anyway for the first case where it is somehow marked as hidden you should make it visible. This can be done with javascript. Try this method before clicking on your element:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.display='initial';",element);
```

You can also use

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.display='visible';",element);
```

but i find "initial" work more efficiently most of the time. You may need to perform this action to the parent element if this is the one being hidden.

In the second case you should probably use something like this before click:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);" + "window.scrollBy(0,-100);", element);
```

The "window.scrollBy(0,-100);" is mandatory argument for firefox browser but optional for chrome.

Comment: Thank you @gmitsios but I am using selenium with Python not Java.

Comment: Ok use driver.execute_script(javascript code here) then instead of js.executeScript(). The rest is javascript which remains the same.